# Google colab, data frame data displayed not in columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

Why data not displayed in columns?
[image]

df.info() also display data not in columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see columns seperate with **;**. so you you have to define a separator :

```
df = pd.read_csv("abc.csv", sep = ';' )
```